# Using Stokes' Theorem to find the flux on F

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

I have been working on a Stokes' Theorem problem. (Thank you @Prasiortle for your help in [this problem.][1]) This is the question and my work so far. The reason why I'm feeling hesitant is that although my integral is very neat, the final answer seems to be messier - which is not characteristic of these textbook problems. I don't see my error - but I don't really know what I'm doing yet. Did I mess up over here? I am taking an independent study course, so I don't have a teacher that I can ask these questions to - I appreciate all advice!

Thanks!

*Edit: I had had this down in pictures, but I will change it to mathJax. I saw that I had forgotten to put the norm of my normal vector in to the dS, so I added that. This makes my answer more manageable than it was originally, but I'm still not sure (especially because it is a large number). Here is my work:

Use Stokes’ Theorem to evaluate $\int_{C}\ F\bullet\ dr$ where $C$ is the boundary of the portion of the paraboloid $x=y^2+z^2$ with $x\le4,$ n to the back, $F =<yz,y-4,2xy>$

Parametrize $C: x=r^2,y=r\cos{\left(\theta\right)},\mathrm{\mathrm{\ }and\ }z=r\sin{\left(\theta\right)}$ and so: $\langle r^2,r\ cos(\theta),r\ sin(\theta)\rangle\\
 C_r=\left\langle 
 2r,cos{\left(\theta\right)},sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right\rangle\\
 C_\theta=\left\langle0,-rsin{\left(\theta\right)},rcos{\left(\theta\right)}\right\rangle\\
\left|\begin{matrix}i&j&k\\2r&cos\left(\theta\right)&sin\left(\theta\right)\\0&-rsin\left(\theta\right)&rcos\left(\theta\right)\\\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{\left\langle r,-2r^2cos{\left(\theta\right)},-2r^2sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right\rangle}{r\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\\
 \nabla\times F=\left\langle2x,-y,-z\right\rangle=\left\langle2r^2,-rcos{\left(\theta\right)},-rsin{\left(\theta\right)}\right\rangle\\
 \left(\nabla\times F\right)\bullet{n}=\frac{4r^2}{\sqrt{4r^2+1}}\\
 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{4}{\frac{4r^2}{\sqrt{4r^2+1}}\left(r\sqrt{1+4r^2}\right)drd\theta}=512\pi$

Comment: Anyway, is there a question here any more after your update? If you’ve managed to answer this question on your own, then post that solution as an answer once you’re able to (there’s some time delay before you’re allowed to do that) instead of adding it to the question.

Comment: @amd yes, I still have a question - It still seems like a very large number to me and I want to know if I'm right.

Comment: The reason why I'm so unsure is because its a self-guided course and I am really not confident that I understood it yet - but I can't ask the teacher.

Comment: Is the end cap at $x=4$ supposed to be part of the surface? The integral over the volume includes that.

Comment: @amd I put that in - its in my bounds of r. Should those bounds really be until 2.

Comment: The upper bound in the inner integral should be $2$, not $4$. As a remark, notice that you divide by the norm of $\boldsymbol n$ and then multiply by it. You can just write $d\boldsymbol S = (\boldsymbol r_u \times \boldsymbol r_v) \hspace {1.5px} du dv$ (and choose the direction; if the condition says that $\boldsymbol n$ is to the back, that probably means that $\boldsymbol n$ is pointing in the negative $x$-direction).

Comment: @Maxim I see what you  are saying about dividing and multiplying by the norm of n. When you say I can just write $dS=(r_u\times r_v)$, how does that change what I did?